# How to view data before insert in VBA?

Tags: vba, debugging, insert, accpac

I have a VBA macro (not an Excel macro) that is pulling data from one system and inserting into another that is failing.

Is there a way to write to a text file the data it is trying to insert? I want to see the state of the data before trying to insert.

What the code is supposed to do: Take returns from ERP and insert into Accpac/GL system. A custom macro was written to do this, however it will not pull in old returns. I believe it is because of the period being lock in Accpac, however I want to see where it would be referencing such data.

The mega macro:

```
Option Explicit
Private dsDate1 As AccpacDataSrc.AccpacCustomField
Private dsDate2 As AccpacDataSrc.AccpacCustomField
Private blnCancel As Boolean

Private Sub cmdExit_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub cmdReceipts_Click()
DoRecpts
'DoCSV
Print #2, "Interface ended" & Now
Close #2
Shell "Notepad.exe " & "ReceiptProcess" & Format(Date, "mmddyyyy") & ".txt"
End Sub

Private Sub DoRecpts()
blnCancel = False
'Dim vRCHead As AccpacView
'Dim vRCDet As AccpacView
'Dim vRCComm As AccpacView
'Dim vRCVend As AccpacView
'Dim vRCAddit As AccpacView
'Dim vRCFunct As AccpacView
'Dim vRCPO As AccpacView
'Dim vRCHeadO As AccpacView
'Dim vRCCost As AccpacView
'Dim vRCDetO As AccpacView
'Dim vRCVendO As AccpacView
'Dim vRCAdditO As AccpacView
'Dim vRCCostDist As AccpacView
'Dim vRCProrate As AccpacView


'Dim vRTHead As AccpacView
'Dim vRTDet As AccpacView
'Dim vRTComm As AccpacView
'Dim vRTFunct As AccpacView
'Dim vRTHeadO As AccpacView
'Dim vRTDetO As AccpacView

Dim vRTHead As AccpacCOMAPI.AccpacView
Dim vRTDet As AccpacCOMAPI.AccpacView
Dim vRTComm As AccpacCOMAPI.AccpacView
Dim vRTFunct As AccpacCOMAPI.AccpacView
Dim vRTHeadO As AccpacCOMAPI.AccpacView
Dim vRTDetO As AccpacCOMAPI.AccpacView
'new
Dim vRTLineLots As AccpacCOMAPI.AccpacView
Dim vRTLineSerials As AccpacCOMAPI.AccpacView

Dim vVend As AccpacCOMAPI.AccpacView

Dim rsRecpt As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strErrLog As String
Dim blnErr As Boolean
Dim strCLast As String
Dim strCCurr As String
Dim strTLast As String
Dim strTCurr As String
Dim blnReturn As Boolean
Dim blnHeaderr As Boolean
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim vLast As String
Dim vCurr As String
Dim blnBadVend As Boolean
Dim start As Variant
Dim blnEOF As Boolean

blnEOF = False

'dbCmp.OpenView "PO0700", vRCHead
'dbCmp.OpenView "PO0710", vRCDet
'dbCmp.OpenView "PO0695", vRCComm
'dbCmp.OpenView "PO0718", vRCVend
'dbCmp.OpenView "PO0714", vRCAddit
'dbCmp.OpenView "PO0699", vRCFunct
'dbCmp.OpenView "PO0705", vRCPO
'dbCmp.OpenView "PO0703", vRCHeadO
'dbCmp.OpenView "PO0696", vRCCost
'dbCmp.OpenView "PO0717", vRCDetO
'dbCmp.OpenView "PO0721", vRCVendO
'dbCmp.OpenView "PO0719", vRCAdditO
'dbCmp.OpenView "PO0697", vRCCostDist
'dbCmp.OpenView "PO0704", vRCProrate

dbCmp.OpenView "PO0731", vRTHead
dbCmp.OpenView "PO0735", vRTDet
dbCmp.OpenView "PO0729", vRTComm
dbCmp.OpenView "PO0730", vRTFunct
dbCmp.OpenView "PO0738", vRTHeadO
dbCmp.OpenView "PO0739", vRTDetO
dbCmp.OpenView "PO0799", vRTLineLots
dbCmp.OpenView "PO0790", vRTLineSerials

dbCmp.OpenView "AP0015", vVend

'vRCHead.Compose Array(vRCComm, vRCDet, vRCVend, _
'            vRCAddit, vRCFunct, vRCPO, vRCHeadO, vRCCost)
'
'vRCDet.Compose Array(vRCHead, vRCComm, vRCFunct, _
'            Nothing, Nothing, vRCDetO)
'
'
'vRCComm.Compose Array(vRCHead, vRCDet)
'vRCVend.Compose Array(vRCHead, vRCAddit, vRCFunct, vRCVendO)
'
'vRCAddit.Compose Array(vRCVend, vRCFunct, vRCHead, Nothing, _
'                                        Nothing, vRCCost)
'
'vRCFunct.Compose Array(vRCHead, vRCComm, vRCDet, vRCAddit, _
'                            vRCVend, vRCPO, vRCCost)
'
'vRCPO.Compose Array(vRCHead, vRCFunct)
'vRCHeadO.Compose Array(vRCHead)
'vRCCost.Compose Array(vRCAddit, vRCVend, vRCHead, vRCFunct, vRCCostDist)
'vRCDetO.Compose Array(vRCDet)
'vRCVendO.Compose Array(vRCVend)
'vRCAdditO.Compose Array(vRCAddit)
'vRCCostDist.Compose Array(Nothing, vRCCost, vRCAddit)
'vRCProrate.Compose Array(vRCCost, vRCDet)

'vRTHead.Compose Array(vRTComm, vRTDet, vRTFunct, vRTHeadO)
'vRTDet.Compose Array(vRTHead, vRTComm, vRTFunct, _
'            Nothing, Nothing, vRTDetO)
'vRTComm.Compose Array(vRTHead, vRTDet)
'vRTFunct.Compose Array(vRTHead, vRTComm, vRTDet)
'vRTHeadO.Compose Array(vRTHead)
'vRTDetO.Compose Array(vRTDet)

vRTHead.Compose Array(vRTComm, vRTDet, vRTFunct, vRTHeadO)
vRTDet.Compose Array(vRTHead, vRTComm, vRTFunct, Nothing, Nothing, vRTDetO, vRTLineLots, vRTLineSerials)
vRTComm.Compose Array(vRTHead, vRTDet)
vRTFunct.Compose Array(vRTHead, vRTComm, vRTDet, vRTLineLots, vRTLineSerials)
vRTHeadO.Compose Array(vRTHead)
vRTDetO.Compose Array(vRTDet)
vRTLineLots.Compose Array(vRTDet, Nothing, Nothing)
vRTLineSerials.Compose Array(vRTDet, Nothing, Nothing)

On Error GoTo RecErr
strErrLog = "ReturnErrors.log"


' To filter zero dollar receipts, field rec_header.rh_rtd_cost<>0

strSQL = "SELECT rec_header.*, rec_detail.*, vendors.*, inv.* " & _
         "FROM rec_header " & _
         "INNER JOIN rec_detail ON rec_header.rh_id = rec_detail.rd_id " & _
         "INNER JOIN vendors ON rec_header.rh_vendor = vendors.ve_id " & _
         "INNER JOIN inv ON rec_detail.rd_id3 = inv.inv_id3 " & _
         "WHERE rec_detail.rd_pst_cou_dtm >= '" & Format(feDateStrt, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") & _
         "' and rec_detail.rd_pst_cou_dtm < '" & _
        Format(DateAdd("D", 1, feDateEnd), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") & _
         "' and rec_header.rh_status = 'PST'"

rsRecpt.Open strSQL, Conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

With rsRecpt
    Do Until .EOF
        vCurr = .Fields("ve_acct")
        If vCurr <> vLast Then
            blnBadVend = False
            vVend.Init
            vVend.Browse "VENDORID =" & .Fields("ve_acct"), True
            If vVend.Fetch = False Then GoTo NoVend
        End If
        If .Fields("rd_total") < 0 Then
'            strCCurr = .Fields("rh_id")
'
'            If strCCurr <> strCLast Then
'                blnReturn = False
'                If strCLast <> "" Then
'                   If blnBadVend = True Then GoTo NextDetail
'                   vRCHead.Insert
'                   If strCLast <> "" Then Print #2, "Receipt " & strCLast & " entered."
'                   If blnHeaderr = False Then lngCount = lngCount + 1
'                   blnHeaderr = False
'                   DoEvents
'                   If blnCancel = True Then GoTo FinishUp
'                End If
'RedoRCHead:
'                vRCHead.RecordGenerate False
'                lblInfo.Caption = "Doing receipt no: " & .Fields("rh_id") & "..."
'                Me.Repaint
'
'                vRCHead.Fields("VDCODE") = .Fields("ve_acct")
'                vRCHead.Fields("RCPNUMBER") = CStr(.Fields("rh_id"))
'                vRCHead.Fields("DESCRIPTIO") = "Receiver import from Apropos"
'                vRCHead.Fields("REFERENCE") = .Fields("rh_po_id")
'                vRCHead.Fields("DATE") = .Fields("rh_arrival_date")
'
'                vRCHeadO.Fields("OPTFIELD").PutWithoutVerification "PO"
'                vRCHeadO.Fields("VALUE") = .Fields("rh_po_id")
'                vRCHeadO.Insert
'            End If
'            vRCDet.RecordGenerate False
'            vRCDet.Fields("ITEMNO") = "INV"
'            vRCDet.Fields("ITEMDESC") = .Fields("inv_id3") & " - " & .Fields("inv_desc")
'            vRCDet.Fields("RQRECEIVED") = .Fields("rd_total")
'            vRCDet.Fields("UNITCOST") = Round(.Fields("rd_cost"), 2)
'            If Not IsNull(.Fields("rh_spec_instr")) Then
'                vRCComm.RecordGenerate False
'                vRCComm.Fields("COMMENTTYP") = 1
'                vRCComm.Fields("COMMENT") = .Fields("rh_spec_instr")
'                vRCComm.Insert
'            End If
'
'            If Not IsNull(.Fields("rh_recv_instr")) Then
'                vRCComm.RecordGenerate False
'                vRCComm.Fields("COMMENTTYP") = 1
'                vRCComm.Fields("COMMENT") = .Fields("rh_recv_instr")
'                vRCComm.Insert
'            End If
'            vRCDet.Insert
'            strCLast = strCCurr
'        Else
            strTCurr = .Fields("rh_id")
            If strTCurr <> strTLast Then
                blnReturn = True
                If strTLast <> "" Then
                   vRTHead.Insert
                   If strTLast <> "" Then Print #2, "Return " & strTLast & " entered."
                   If blnHeaderr = False Then lngCount = lngCount + 1
                   blnHeaderr = False
                   If blnBadVend = True Then GoTo NextDetail
                   DoEvents
                   If blnCancel = True Then GoTo FinishUp

                End If
RedoRtHead:

                vRTHead.RecordGenerate False
                lblInfo.Caption = "Doing return no: " & .Fields("rh_id") & "..."
                Me.Repaint

                vRTHead.Fields("VDCODE") = .Fields("ve_acct")
                vRTHead.Fields("RETNUMBER") = CStr(.Fields("rh_id"))
                vRTHead.Fields("DESCRIPTIO") = "Return import from Apropos"
                vRTHead.Fields("REFERENCE") = .Fields("rh_po_id")
                vRTHead.Fields("DATE") = .Fields("rh_arrival_date")

                vRTHeadO.Fields("OPTFIELD").PutWithoutVerification "PO"
                vRTHeadO.Fields("VALIFTEXT") = .Fields("rh_po_id")
                vRTHeadO.Insert

            End If
            vRTDet.RecordGenerate False
            vRTDet.Fields("ITEMNO") = "INV"
            vRTDet.Fields("ITEMDESC") = .Fields("inv_id3") & " - " & .Fields("inv_desc")
            vRTDet.Fields("RQRETURNED") = -.Fields("rd_total")
            vRTDet.Fields("UNITCOST") = Round(.Fields("rd_cost"), 2)
            If Not IsNull(.Fields("rh_spec_instr")) Then
                vRTComm.RecordGenerate False
                vRTComm.Fields("COMMENTTYP") = 1
                vRTComm.Fields("COMMENT") = .Fields("rh_spec_instr")
                vRTComm.Insert
            End If

            If Not IsNull(.Fields("rh_recv_instr")) Then
                vRTComm.RecordGenerate False
                vRTComm.Fields("COMMENTTYP") = 1
                vRTComm.Fields("COMMENT") = .Fields("rh_recv_instr")
                vRTComm.Insert
            End If
            vRTDet.Insert
            strTLast = strTCurr
        End If
NextDetail:
        If .BOF Or .EOF Then Exit Do
        .MoveNext
        vLast = vCurr
    Loop
'    If blnReturn Then vRTHead.Insert Else vRCHead.Insert
    If strTCurr <> "" And blnEOF = False Then
        blnEOF = True
        vRTHead.Insert
    End If
    .Close
End With
FinishUp:
'Set rsRecpt = Nothing
'Set vRTHead = Nothing
'Set vRTDet = Nothing
'Set vRTComm = Nothing
'Set vRTFunct = Nothing
'Set vRCHead = Nothing
'Set vRCDet = Nothing
'Set vRCAddit = Nothing
'Set vRCComm = Nothing
'Set vRCFunct = Nothing
MsgBox lngCount & " returns have been entered into ACCPAC", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Finished"
If blnErr = True Then Shell "Notepad.exe " & strErrLog
lblInfo.Caption = ""
Me.Repaint

Exit Sub


NoVend:
If vCurr <> vLast Then
    blnBadVend = True
    If blnErr = False Then
        Open strErrLog For Output As #1
        blnErr = True
        Print #1, "The following returns were not entered for the reasons indicated."
    Else
        Open strErrLog For Append As #1
    End If
    If rsRecpt.Fields("rd_total") > 0 Then
        Print #1, "The vendor " & rsRecpt.Fields("ve_acct") & " does not exist so " & strCLast & " was not added."
    Else
        Print #1, "The vendor " & rsRecpt.Fields("ve_acct") & " does not exist so " & strTLast & " was not added."
    End If
    Close #1
End If
GoTo NextDetail


RecErr:

If blnErr = False Then
    Open strErrLog For Output As #1
    blnErr = True
    Print #1, "The following returns were not entered for the reasons indicated."
Else
    Open strErrLog For Append As #1
End If
If AccpacSession.Errors.Count > 0 Then
    If InStr(1, AccpacSession.Errors(0), "already exists") > 0 Then
        Print #1, "The return " & strTLast & _
                    " was not added because it already exists in ACCPAC"
        vRTHead.Cancel
        strTLast = ""
        Close #1
        AccpacSession.Errors.Clear
        Err.Clear
        blnHeaderr = True
        Resume Next
    End If
    If InStr(1, AccpacSession.Errors(0), "compute tax") > 0 Then
        Print #1, "The return " & rsRecpt.Fields("rh_id") & _
                    " was not added because cannot compute tax."
        vRTHead.Cancel
        strTLast = ""
        Close #1
        AccpacSession.Errors.Clear
        Err.Clear
        blnHeaderr = True
        Resume NextDetail
    End If
Else
    Print #1, Err.Description
End If
Close #1
AccpacSession.Errors.Clear
Err.Clear
Resume NextDetail

End Sub

Private Sub feDateEnd_Exit(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
If feDateStrt > feDateEnd Then
    MsgBox "The ending date must be greater than the beginning date"
    feDateEnd = feDateStrt
End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Set dsDate1 = New AccpacDataSrc.AccpacCustomField
Set dsDate2 = New AccpacDataSrc.AccpacCustomField
dsDate1.Init FLD_DATE, FLD_EDITABLE + FLD_ENABLED
dsDate2.Init FLD_DATE, FLD_EDITABLE + FLD_ENABLED
feDateStrt.AccpacField = dsDate1
feDateEnd.AccpacField = dsDate2
feDateStrt = DateAdd("D", -7, Date)
feDateEnd = Date
End Sub

Private Sub DoCSV()
Dim rsRecpt As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim vVend As AccpacView

Dim strSQL As String
Dim strErrLog As String
Dim blnErr As Boolean
Dim strCLast As String
Dim strCCurr As String
Dim strTLast As String
Dim strTCurr As String
Dim blnReturn As Boolean
Dim blnHeaderr As Boolean
Dim lngCCount As Long
Dim lngTCount As Long
Dim lngDetail As Long
Dim lngComment As Long
Dim vLast As String
Dim vCurr As String
Dim blnBadVend As Boolean
Dim start As Variant
Dim lngVendErr As Long

dbCmp.OpenView "AP0015", vVend

strSQL = "SELECT rec_header.*, rec_detail.*, vendors.*, inv.* " & _
         "FROM rec_header " & _
         "INNER JOIN rec_detail ON rec_header.rh_id = rec_detail.rd_id " & _
         "INNER JOIN vendors ON rec_header.rh_vendor = vendors.ve_id " & _
         "INNER JOIN inv ON rec_detail.rd_id3 = inv.inv_id3 " & _
         "WHERE rec_detail.rd_pst_cou_dtm >= '" & Format(feDateStrt, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") & _
         "' and rec_detail.rd_pst_cou_dtm < '" & Format(DateAdd("D", 1, feDateEnd), "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") & _
         "' and rec_header.rh_status = 'PST'"

rsRecpt.Open strSQL, Conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

Open AccpacSession.ProgramsPathOnServer & "Receipt Import.csv" For Output As #2
Open AccpacSession.ProgramsPathOnServer & "Return Import.csv" For Output As #3

CreateHeaderInfo   ' Put the header line in the csv file.

With rsRecpt
    Do Until .EOF
        vCurr = .Fields("ve_acct")
        If vCurr <> vLast Then   ' Check to see if the vendor exists
            blnBadVend = False
            vVend.Init
            vVend.Browse "VENDORID =" & .Fields("ve_acct"), True
            If vVend.Fetch = False Then
                lngVendErr = 1
                GoTo VendErr
            Else    ' if the vendor is inactive or on hold.
                If vVend.Fields("SWACTV") = 0 Then
                    lngVendErr = 2
                    GoTo VendErr
                End If
                If vVend.Fields("SWHOLD") = 1 Then
                    lngVendErr = 3
                    GoTo VendErr
                End If
            End If
        End If

        If .Fields("rd_total") > 0 Then  ' if the amount is >0 it's a receipt.
                strCCurr = .Fields("rh_id")

            If strCCurr <> strCLast Then   ' If the current receipt isn't the same as the last.
                If blnHeaderr = False Then lngCCount = lngCCount + 1
                blnHeaderr = False
                ' Write a header record.
                Write #2, 1, lngCCount, Format(.Fields("rh_arrival_date"), "YYYYMMDD"), _
                            CStr(.Fields("rh_id")), .Fields("ve_acct"), "Receiver import from Apropos", _
                            .Fields("rh_po_id")

                lngDetail = 0
                lngComment = 0
                lblInfo.Caption = "Doing receipt no: " & .Fields("rh_id") & "..."
                Me.Repaint

                ' Write the optional field
                Write #2, 7, lngCCount, "PO", .Fields("rh_po_id")
            End If  ' End of header writing

            ' Write the detail line
            lngDetail = lngDetail + 100
            Write #2, 2, lngCCount, lngDetail, "INV", "", _
                    .Fields("inv_id3") & " - " & .Fields("inv_desc"), _
                    1, lngDetail, "EA", .Fields("rd_total"), Round(.Fields("rd_cost"), 2)

            ' if there is a special instruction
            If Not IsNull(.Fields("rh_spec_instr")) Then
                lngComment = lngComment + 10
                Write #2, 3, lngCCount, lngComment, lngDetail, 1, .Fields("rh_spec_instr")
            End If
            ' if there is a receiver instruction
            If Not IsNull(.Fields("rh_recv_instr")) Then
                lngComment = lngComment + 10
                Write #2, 3, lngCCount, lngComment, lngDetail, 1, .Fields("rh_recv_instr")
            End If
            strCLast = strCCurr
        Else
            strTCurr = .Fields("rh_id")

            If strTCurr <> strTLast Then   ' If the current receipt isn't the same as the last.
                If blnHeaderr = False Then lngTCount = lngTCount + 1
                blnHeaderr = False
                ' Write a header record.
                Write #2, 1, lngTCount, Format(.Fields("rh_arrival_date"), "YYYYMMDD"), _
                            CStr(.Fields("rh_id")), .Fields("ve_acct"), "Receiver import from Apropos", _
                            .Fields("rh_po_id")

                lngDetail = 0
                lngComment = 0
                lblInfo.Caption = "Doing receipt no: " & .Fields("rh_id") & "..."
                Me.Repaint

                ' Write the optional field
                Write #2, 7, lngTCount, "PO", .Fields("rh_po_id")
            End If  ' End of header writing

            ' Write the detail line
            lngDetail = lngDetail + 100
            Write #2, 2, lngTCount, lngDetail, "INV", "", _
                    .Fields("inv_id3") & " - " & .Fields("inv_desc"), _
                    1, lngDetail, "EA", .Fields("rd_total"), Round(.Fields("rd_cost"), 2)

            ' if there is a special instruction
            If Not IsNull(.Fields("rh_spec_instr")) Then
                lngComment = lngComment + 10
                Write #2, 3, lngTCount, lngComment, lngDetail, 1, .Fields("rh_spec_instr")
            End If
            ' if there is a receiver instruction
            If Not IsNull(.Fields("rh_recv_instr")) Then
                lngComment = lngComment + 10
                Write #2, 3, lngTCount, lngComment, lngDetail, 1, .Fields("rh_recv_instr")
            End If
            strTLast = strTCurr
        End If
NextDetail:
        If .BOF Or .EOF Then Exit Do
        .MoveNext
        vLast = vCurr
    Loop
End With

Set vVend = Nothing
Close #2
Close #3

Exit Sub


VendErr:
If vCurr <> vLast Then
    blnBadVend = True
    If blnErr = False Then
        Open strErrLog For Output As #1
        blnErr = True
        Print #1, "The following receipts were not entered for the reasons indicated."
    Else
        Open strErrLog For Append As #1
    End If

    Select Case lngVendErr
    Case 1
        If rsRecpt.Fields("rd_total") > 0 Then
            Print #1, "The vendor " & rsRecpt.Fields("ve_acct") & _
                        " does not exist so " & strCLast & " was not added."
        Else
            Print #1, "The vendor " & rsRecpt.Fields("ve_acct") & _
                        " does not exist so " & strTLast & " was not added."
        End If
    Case 2
        If rsRecpt.Fields("rd_total") > 0 Then
            Print #1, "The vendor " & rsRecpt.Fields("ve_acct") & _
                        " is inactive so " & strCLast & " was not added."
        Else
            Print #1, "The vendor " & rsRecpt.Fields("ve_acct") & _
                        " is inactive so " & strTLast & " was not added."
        End If
    Case 3
        If rsRecpt.Fields("rd_total") > 0 Then
            Print #1, "The vendor " & rsRecpt.Fields("ve_acct") & _
                        " is on hold so " & strCLast & " was not added."
        Else
            Print #1, "The vendor " & rsRecpt.Fields("ve_acct") & _
                        " is on hold so " & strTLast & " was not added."
        End If
    End Select
    Close #1
End If
GoTo NextDetail

End Sub

Private Sub CreateHeaderInfo()
Open "C:\Clients\Zumiez\test.txt" For Output As #2
Write #2, "RECTYPE", "RCPHSEQ", "DATE", "RCPNUMBER", "VDCODE", "DESCRIPTIO", "REFERENCE"
Write #2, "RECTYPE", "RCPHSEQ", "RCPLREV", "ITEMNO", "LOCATION", "ITEMDESC", "HASCOMMENT", "RCPCSEQ", "RCPUNIT", "RQRECEIVED", "UNITCOST"
Write #2, "RECTYPE", "RCPHSEQ", "RCPCREV", "RCPCSEQ", "COMMENTTYP", "COMMENT"
Write #2, "RECTYPE", "RCPHSEQ", "VDCODE"
Write #2, "RECTYPE", "RCPHSEQ", "VDCODE", "RCPSREV"
Write #2, "RECTYPE", "RCPHSEQ", "VDCODE", "RCPSREV", "LSEQ"
Write #2, "RECTYPE", "RCPHSEQ", "OPTFIELD", "VALUE"
Write #2, "RECTYPE", "RCPHSEQ", "RCPLREV", "OPTFIELD"
Write #2, "RECTYPE", "RCPHSEQ", "VDCODE", "OPTFIELD"
Write #2, "RECTYPE", "RCPHSEQ", "VDCODE", "RCPSREV", "OPTFIELD"
Close #2
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like this macro is creating PO Returns in Sage ERP 300 (Accpac) based on the results of the query.  You thought that the issue might be related to a locked fiscal period.  The line vRTHeader.Fields("DATE")... is where the Fiscal Year/Period of the return will be determined.  You didn't indicate at what point that the macro is failing.  Also, the error trapping should loop through each of the errors.  Can you edit your code to remove the comment lines?

Comment: When processing, it just says '0 returns processed', which isn't helpful when you know you have 10+ returns hanging out. We forced an error message box that said "Invalid input. Fiscal period 6 for fiscal year 2014 is locked for Purchase Orders in Common Services' Fiscal Calendar'. We forced the error message to happen after "GoTo NextDetail RecErr:"

Comment: One option is to pre-validate the data to check that the period is open.  I agree that the errors returned are not always informative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write out the field data of each of the Sage views before you call the .Insert or .Update methods you can do a simple loop to go through each of the fields in the view.  Something like:

```
Sub DumpViewFields(aView As AccpacCOMAPI.AccpacView, aFileNumber as long)

    Dim idx As Integer
    Dim output As String

    'Get the headers
    For idx = 0 To aView.Fields.Count - 1
    output = output & CStr(aView.Fields(idx).Name) & Chr(9)
    Next idx
    Print aFileNumber, output

    'Get the data fields
    output = ""
    For idx = 0 To aView.Fields.Count - 1
        output = output & CStr(aView.Fields(idx).Value) & Chr(9)
    Next idx
    Print aFileNumber, output

End Sub
```

I've over simplified the writing of the field values to a file but you get the idea.